# SharedPreferences - OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I googled this and found a few answers which I find confusing since I am a beginner. I am trying to implement the `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` to my `SharedPreferences` to make something happen with the change.

My code so far is:

```
final SharedPreferences rates_storage = this.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("uk.chiraggalaiya.test", 0);
final SharedPreferences.Editor rates_storage_editor = rates_storage.edit();

Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        rates_storage_editor.putString("something", "something");
        rates_storage_editor.apply();
    }
});
```

However now I am not sure how to implement the `OnChangeListener()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use following code snippet to register your ChangListener for the SharedPreference:

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefListener = 
        new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key) {
        ....
    }
};
rates_storage.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefListener);
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much; now I look at the other solutions and see how they work(!) @Hungry Coder