# How to implement SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener?

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

What I'm doing is this :

```
class Act extends AppCompatActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
```

After that override one method

```
 @Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {       

}
```

I'm changing my keys in service class using SharedPreferences I want to get notified as soon as preferences in Service class gets changed.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SharedPreferences - OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272406/sharedpreferences-onsharedpreferencechangelistener)

Comment: What to do inside overrided onSharedPreferenceChanged? I'm debugging control is not getting in.

Comment: do you have this in your code: `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(actClassInstance);`?

Comment: `onSharedPreferenceChanged` called when a shared preference is changed, added, or removed. This may be called even if a preference is set to its existing value. Parameter `sharedPreference` is the SharedPreferences that received the change and
`key` is the key of the preference that was changed, added, or removed

Answer (score 0):

You must also register and unregister the listener with the Shared Preference object you are using.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
   SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```